# static keyword not working in C (Visual Studio)

Tags: c

Question -
N numbers are entered by the user (N is also given by the user). Store the numbers in
an array. Write a C function which deletes all the second largest elements and
rearranges the array. The program should appropriately print the new array and the
value of N. For e.g if N=7 and the elements are 7 11 13 11 8 7 4 the output should be
N=5 and the array is 7 13 8 7 4

My Code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int secondLargest(int arr[], int n);
int indexOfSecondLargest(int arr[], int n, int max2);
void deleteElement(int arr[], int n, int index);
void deleteSecondLargest(int arr[], int n);
void printArray(int arr[], int n);

int main() 
{
    static int n;
    printf("Enter value of n \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[100];

    printf("Enter n numbers \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }    

    deleteSecondLargest(arr, n);

    printf("New value of n = %d and the array is \n", n);
    
    printArray(arr, n);
    
    return 0;
}

int secondLargest(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max1 = arr[0], max2 = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max1)
        {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = arr[i];            
        }
        if (arr[i] > max2 && arr[i] < max1)
        {
            max2 = arr[i];
        }       
    }
    
    return max2;
}

int indexOfSecondLargest(int arr[], int n, int max2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == max2)
        {
            return i;
        }        
    }
    
    return -1;
}

void deleteElement(int arr[], int n, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }

    n = n - 1;
}

void deleteSecondLargest(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max2 = secondLargest(arr, n);

    int index = indexOfSecondLargest(arr, n, max2);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        deleteElement(arr, n, index);
        index = indexOfSecondLargest(arr, n, max2);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }    
}
```

My Output -

```
Enter value of n 
7
Enter n numbers 
7 11 13 11 8 7 4
New value of n = 7 and the array is 
7 13 8 7 4 4 4
```

Even though I am using `static` keyword before `int n`, the value of `n` is not getting updated to 5 in `main()` function. I even tried putting `int n` as a global variable but still it doesn't work.
Can someone help me ??

Answer (score 2):

Adding `static` to `int n;` says “This `n` persists through all of program execution.” it does not say “This `n` is the only `n` in the whole program.” Where a parameter `n` is declared, as in `void deleteElement(int arr[], int n, int index)`, that creates an `n` different from the `n` in `main`.

However, even if no parameter is declared with the name `n`, an `n` declared inside `main` is not visible in any other function. To use the same `n` throughout the program, you need to declare `int n;` or `static int n;` outside of any function, anywhere before the first function that uses `n`, and you need to not declare any other `n`.

That would likely solve this problem for you. However, it is bad practice to use external identifiers for objects. Instead, you should use `int n;` in `main` and modify `deleteElement` so that it provides `main` with the updated value. It could do this by returning an `int` instead of `void`, or you could modify `deleteElement` to take a pointer to an `int` instead of taking an `int`, by making the parameter `int *n`. Then you would have to use it inside the function as `*n` instead of `n`.